# Unable to build iOS after renaming Xcode project flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I have an issue guys. For some reason, I decided to rename my Xcode project runner folder before sending to the apple store. Now I wanted to rebuild for iOS with this command: `flutter build ios`. But I get this error each time:

```
Expected ios/Runner.xcodeproj but this file is missing.
Application not configured for iOS
```

I also tried building this with Xcode. I got this error each time:

```
/Users/apple/FlutterProjects/kashbase/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Kashbase/Pods-Kashbase.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "Kashbase" in project "Kashbase") (in target 'Kashbase')
```

What does this mean and how can resolve this? Any helpful effort will be greatly appreciated.